# SQL Server: how to re-use SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Tags: sql-server

I want to do some sort of "copy-paste" of one row in the table `creneau`. This row has a one-to-many relationship with table `creneau_jour`. Thus I'd like to duplicate all the rows of this relationship too. I'm trying to do what I've done with MySQL but I'm missing something but dont know why:

```
INSERT INTO [RdV].[dbo].[creneau]
           ([libelle]
           ,[debut]
           ,[fin]
           ,[heure_debut]
           ,[duree])
     SELECT
        'Encore !!!', debut, fin, heure_debut, duree 
     FROM 
        creneau 
     WHERE 
        id = 1;

INSERT INTO  [RdV].[dbo].[creneau_jour]
           ([creneau_id] ,[jour_semaine])
VALUES (
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), SELECT jour_semaine FROM creneau_jour WHERE id=1
);
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just assign that into a variable then Use that variable?

Comment: @Piyush Ok, maybe it's simple for you but it's the first time I'm using SQL server Management Studio... may I ask you to do a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SCOPEIDENTITY INT;
INSERT INTO [RdV].[dbo].[creneau]
           ([libelle]
           ,[debut]
           ,[fin]
           ,[heure_debut]
           ,[duree])
     SELECT 'Encore v3',debut,fin,heure_debut,duree FROM creneau WHERE id=1;

SET @SCOPEIDENTITY = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO  [RdV].[dbo].[creneau_jour] ([creneau_id] ,[jour_semaine])
SELECT @SCOPEIDENTITY, jour_semaine FROM creneau_jour WHERE creneau_id=1
;

GO
```

Comment: you just copy exactly my answer?

Comment: I took out the subquery that you had in there at the time I looked at the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can forget about using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and use `OUTPUT` as part of the `INSERT`, so that you can set a variable with a value from the newly created row.

One such advantage to this method is that if you ever turn on identity insert then @SCOPE_IDENTITY wouldn't work, but the method using OUTPUT would.

```
DECLARE @Identity INT

INSERT INTO [RdV].[dbo].[creneau]
           ([libelle]
           ,[debut]
           ,[fin]
           ,[heure_debut]
           ,[duree])
OUTPUT inserted.IdentityColumn INTO @Identity
     SELECT
        'Encore !!!', debut, fin, heure_debut, duree 
     FROM 
        creneau 
     WHERE 
        id = 1

INSERT INTO  [RdV].[dbo].[creneau_jour]
           ([creneau_id] ,[jour_semaine])
VALUES (
    SELECT @Identity, SELECT jour_semaine FROM creneau_jour WHERE id=1
);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but copy/paste your code doesn't work, i'll tell you tomorrow the exact error.

Comment: Probably `OUTPUT inserted.IdentityColumn INTO @Identity` has the error since IdentityColumn needs to be your column name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DECLARE @SCOPEIDENTITY INT;
INSERT INTO [RdV].[dbo].[creneau]
           ([libelle]
           ,[debut]
           ,[fin]
           ,[heure_debut]
           ,[duree])
     SELECT 'Encore v3',debut,fin,heure_debut,duree FROM creneau WHERE id=1;

SET @SCOPEIDENTITY = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO  [RdV].[dbo].[creneau_jour] ([creneau_id] ,[jour_semaine])
SELECT @SCOPEIDENTITY, jour_semaine FROM creneau_jour WHERE creneau_id=1;

GO
```

Comment: `Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`

Comment: I modified the query , try that

Comment: Almost... I've modified your answer to reflect what's going on, an the error is `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`